# how to solve this js if statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, hex

How to solve this if statement to be true and display alert?
I'm not understand what means 0x4, 0x3, 0x05
what means? and how to solve this if to display the alert

```js
var Ft32A = [
    function (x,y) {return x+y},
    function (x,y) {return x-y},
    function (x,y) {return x/y},
    function (x,y) {return x*y},
    function (x,y) {return x==y},
    function (x,y) {return (y)}
];
function login() {
    var psw = password.value;
    if(
        Ft32A[0x4](psw.length,10)&&
        Ft32A[0x4](Ft32A[0x1](psw.charAt(0x01),psw.charAt(0x2)),0)&&
        Ft32A[0x4]((psw.charAt(6)),Math.abs(Ft32A[0x1](10,11)))&&
        psw.split("_")[1].startsWith(String.fromCharCode(78))&&
        Ft32A[0x4](Ft32A[3](psw.charAt(1),4),0)&&
        Ft32A[0x4](psw.split('_').length,2)&&
        psw.split('_')[0].charAt(psw.split('_')[0].length-1)=="DADADADA".charAt(2) &&
        Ft32A[0x3](psw.charCodeAt(psw.length-1),3)==348 &&
        Ft32A[1](psw.charCodeAt(8),psw.charCodeAt(7))==1 &&
        (Ft32A[0](psw.charCodeAt(8),psw.charCodeAt(7))-1)/2==103 &&
        psw.startsWith("G")
    ) {
        alert("Flag:{"+Ft32A[0x05]("",password.value)+"}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really easy, the code just tells you step by step which position is which character.

Let's go through it line by line

```
Ft32A[0x4](psw.length,10) // The password has 10 digits 
-> ??????????
Ft32A[0x4](Ft32A[0x1](psw.charAt(0x01),psw.charAt(0x2)),0) // Digit 1 and 2 are the same  
-> ?11???????
Ft32A[0x4]((psw.charAt(6)),Math.abs(Ft32A[0x1](10,11))) // Digit 6 is a 1 
-> ?11???1???
psw.split("_")[1].startsWith(String.fromCharCode(78)) //Password has a "_", right part starts with an N
-> ?11?_N1???
 Ft32A[0x4](Ft32A[3](psw.charAt(1),4),0 // Digit 1 times 4 is 0
-> ?00?_N1???
Ft32A[0x4](psw.split('_').length,2) // Contains only 1 _
-> ?00?_N1???
psw.split('_')[0].charAt(psw.split('_')[0].length-1)=="DADADADA".charAt(2) //The last digit before the _ is a D
-> ?00D_N1???
 Ft32A[0x3](psw.charCodeAt(psw.length-1),3)==348 //The last digit is a "t"
-> ?00D_N1??t
 Ft32A[1](psw.charCodeAt(8),psw.charCodeAt(7))==1 // Digit 8 - Digit 7 is one
-> ?00D_N1ABt
Ft32A[0](psw.charCodeAt(8),psw.charCodeAt(7))-1)/2==103 //Digit 8 and 7 are h and g
-> ?00D_N1ght
psw.startsWith("G") //Password starts with a G
-> G00D_N1ght
```

The flag is

> Flag:{G00D_N1ght}

Answer (score 1):

`Ft32A` is a variable containing an array of 6 functions.

```
var Ft32A = [
    function (x,y) {return x+y},
    function (x,y) {return x-y},
    function (x,y) {return x/y},
    function (x,y) {return x*y},
    function (x,y) {return x==y},
    function (x,y) {return (y)}
];
```

To execute the function contained in the first "slot" you could call:

```
Ft32A[0](5, 10); // first function: function (x,y) {return x+y}
```

Where `Ft32A[0]` is the first element (containing the function `function (x,y) {return x+y}`), followed by `(5, 10)` which is the arguments that the function needs, in this case 2 numbers.

You could also reference the first function using the [hexadecimal notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates#Hexadecimal_numbers):

```
Ft32A[0x0](5, 10);
```

And the fifth one with:

```
Ft32A[0x4](5, 10); // fifth function: function (x,y) {return x==y}
```

The `if` statement simply executes some of the functions, each time passing different values. All values returned must be `true` for the if's condition to be validated.

So you have to find the string value that when passed through all these tests, validates the `if` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is ugly as sin... but lets debug it line by line:

```
console.log(0x4);
```

Gives me the answer of `4` this means, this is odd and makes me wonder why we are doing this.

```
Ft32A[0x4](psw.length,10)
```

So this will give me the fifth index of the array `Ft32A`

```
function (x,y) {return x==y}
```

so let's "simplify" this

```
function login() {
var psw = password.value;
if( 
    psw.length == 10 &&
    ((psw.charAt(0x01) - psw.charAt(0x2)) == 0) &&
    ((psw.charAt(6)) == Math.abs((10 - 11))) &&
    psw.split("_")[1].startsWith(String.fromCharCode(78)) &&
    ((psw.charAt(1) * 4) == 0) &&
    (psw.split('_').length == 2)&&
    psw.split('_')[0].charAt(psw.split('_')[0].length-1) == "DADADADA".charAt(2) &&
    (psw.charCodeAt(psw.length-1) * 3) == 348 &&
    (psw.charCodeAt(8) - psw.charCodeAt(7)) == 1 &&
    ((psw.charCodeAt(8) + psw.charCodeAt(7)) - 1) / 2 == 103 &&
    psw.startsWith("G"))
    {
        alert("Flag:{"+password.value+"}");
    }

}
```

This feels to me like either some really bad programmer has written this (someone not knowing about classes) or this is some sort of code challenge?

As for something that will pass this, I have literally no idea.

I would suggest taking it line by line and figuring it out from the information here.

Hope this helps

Comment: `Ft32A[0x4]` returns the fifth element, which is `function (x,y) {return x==y}`